# Google Cloud Datastore commit conflict detection

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Firestore in Datastore Mode. I'm not using the client library provided by Google or anyone and communicating with Datastore directly via generated (by Google) from `proto grpc` library (the one which anyone can generate). I use it because high-level clients are not supposed to work with entity version and conflicts detection mechanism.

I'm doing a transactional update and specifying conflict detection strategy base version (each entity might contain the previously known version).

**The question is**, will the whole commit operation fail when there is a versions conflict in any entity? If it not fails, would such commit be applied in Datastore and I will not do rollback with simple transaction rollback call.

Will I still need to implement my own standalone rollback outside of that transaction via a separate call to the Datastore?

*Mutations create*

[image]

*Commit and decision on what to do next*

[image]

I already looked through documentation and is far from completion on this question. This is the only thing I found.

[image]

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.datastore.v1#google.datastore.v1.MutationResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastore imposes restrictions on what can complete inside a single transaction. Usually, a concurrent transaction/modification gets replied when there is a commit conflict. You can reproduce this by, starting two transactions that write to the same document, commit and see the expected behaviour.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/transactions#what_can_be_done_in_a_transaction):

> When two or more transactions simultaneously attempt to modify entities in one or more common entity groups, only the first transaction to commit its changes can succeed; all the others will fail on commit. Because of this design, using entity groups limits the number of concurrent writes you can do on any entity in the groups. When a transaction starts, Datastore uses optimistic concurrency control by checking the last update time for the entity groups used in the transaction. Upon committing a transaction for the entity groups, Datastore again checks the last update time for the entity groups used in the transaction. If it has changed since the initial check, an exception is thrown.

The best way would be to reproduce it quickly and see the exact behaviour. The question, will the whole commit operation fail when there is a versions conflict in any entity?

Yes.

The wrapper will automatically retry your transaction. The `Golang` datastore running transaction library should provide more insight into how it behaves. For more information, look at the [`RunInTransaction`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/datastore/transaction.go#L167) seen below and see how it evaluates the transaction.

```
func (c *Client) RunInTransaction(ctx context.Context, f func(tx *Transaction) error, opts ...TransactionOption) (cmt *Commit, err error) {
        ctx = trace.StartSpan(ctx, "cloud.google.com/go/datastore.RunInTransaction")
        defer func() { trace.EndSpan(ctx, err) }()
     
        settings := newTransactionSettings(opts)
        for n := 0; n < settings.attempts; n++ {
     tx, err := c.newTransaction(ctx, settings)
     if err != nil {
     return nil, err
     }
     if err := f(tx); err != nil {
     _ = tx.Rollback()
     return nil, err
     }
     if cmt, err := tx.Commit(); err != ErrConcurrentTransaction {
     return cmt, err
     }
     // Pass this transaction's ID to the retry transaction to preserve
     // transaction priority.
     if !settings.readOnly {
     settings.prevID = tx.id
     }
        }
        return nil, ErrConcurrentTransaction
    }
```